# Macbook retina 13" Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter. Does anybody test it?

Tags: macbook-pro, external-monitor

Recently I bought a HDMI to VGA adaptor for my macbook but it doesn't work on ubuntu 14.04. Again I am going to connect my macbook to a projector with VGA input. I need to know if anybody test Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter ?
If anybody know any solution to connect macbook pro retina to VGA input please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have connected my 13" retina (mgx82) Macbook pro to VGA video projector(monitor) with mini display to VGA adaptor and it works fine.